# how to create internal links using pypdf package in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to link index with the content using internal link `add_link()` and `set_link()` in `pyfpdf` but its not working.

```
rtype1=pdf.add_link()
pdf.set_link(rtype1,y=0.0,page=-1)
pdf.cell(0,8,"Link",0,1,'',False,link=rtype1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show code what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code he is trying is in the code box.  I'm more curious about what is the result.  "its not working" is vague.  Is it causing an error or is just a logic error.  If its a programming error, which line is the problem?

Comment: You are mixing values with keyword arguments. Just put them all as keyword arguments like pdf.cell(w=0.8, h=0, ..., link=rtype1)